# Mono16 images displayed as 8 bits in rostopic echo

Tags: ros, rostopic-echo, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there !

I generate a 16bits image (stored in an opencv CV_16U) that I convert to a msg using cv_bridge with the right encoding (mono16). When I do a rostopic echo on the image topic, I get this kind of output :

> header:    seq: 481   stamp:
> secs: 1456138732
> nsecs: 716579801   frame_id: '' height: 250 width: 1 encoding: mono16
> is_bigendian: 0 step: 2 data: [0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0,
> 9, 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 9,
> 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 11, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 11,
> 0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 13, 0, 9, 0, 11,
> 0, 11, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0,
> 13, 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 11, 0, 13,
> 0, 13, 0, 13, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 14, 0,
> 13, 0, 13, 0, 14, 0, 14, 0, 13, 0, 16,
> 0, 14, 0, 14, 0, 16, 0, 14, 0, 16, 0,
> 14, 0, 192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0]

so the image appears as mono16 but the values displayed never go over 255 and there are 0 appearing between values that I can see are wrong. So looking at this, it looks like it's displaying the image as an 8bit image instead of 16bits image. I can then read the image in my node and the data looks fine so it's just a display issue really.

I haven't thing any mention of this in any answer here so I suspect it's a bug, am I the only one to observe this ?

**Configuration :**
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - ros-indigo full-desktop

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227295/mono16-images-displayed-as-8-bits-in-rostopic-echo/) by [Thomas Guerneve](https://answers.ros.org/users/26028/thomas-guerneve/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is just the encoding of the image data as a byte array. I would assume you'll find twice the byte entries here than you have image pixels. You just have to interpret two bytes as a 16-bit pixel.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas Guerneve](https://answers.ros.org/users/26028/thomas-guerneve/) on 2016-02-24**:
Absolutely, as I said I can read the image and use it without any issue, but it should be displayed properly in rostopic echo, it's handy for debugging...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-02-24**:
It is displayed correctly in rostopic - in the sense that rostopic shows you, what exactly is send as the message. What you are looking for is a semantic interpretation of messages. rostopic cannot do that as it would need to know how to interpret any message. It's also the tool to show raw data.